# How to solve Jquery ajax url. 404 (Not Found).?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

How to solve data.php url: 404 (Not Found). Files are in the same folder. but I get this error in the console. Edidor: SublimeText with Browser Sync live server. Thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ajax.js**

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'data.php',
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);

   },
   error: function(error){

     console.log(error);

   }

  });
 }
```

**index.html**

```
<button onClick="getData()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: For javascript the root is `/` (where index is located). Even if you put your js-script and data.php in `/otherfolder`. So check the path. Could be you need to adjust it to `/otherfolder/data.php`

Comment: However, the error still the same! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you have all 3 files.

1. index.html
2. ajax.js
3. data.php

in the same folder?
If yes, then check file permission. make sure all 3 files have read/write/excute files on windows and 644 on ubuntu/mac.

Comment: Yes, everything is right, but no way! thanks.

Comment: This is the error that I get from the console: **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/test/data.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.**

Comment: CORS (cross origin resource sharing) type of errors occur when calling file and called file are on different servers or atleast when browser thinks of them as different servers. ex: $.ajax({ url: 'https://localhost/data.php', Where as localhost is hosted on http Browser sees https and http are different servers. To avoid CORS issues, especially if all your files are on same server. Use relative path. <script src="ajax.js"> instead of <script src="localhost/ajax.js"> and so on. I hope that fixes it. Let me know

Comment: Didn't work. bro. this issue has tired me a lot, or am I missing something? Let's explain a little bit more. I only have three files which are: **dada.php**, **ajax.js** and **index.html** all are in a same folder named **test** in C directory. ajax file attached in **index.html** like this `<script crs="ajax.js"></script>` placed before the closing `body` tag. Including `jQuery` file also. the **ajax.js** script is like above and that's it.  I used live server,no way, and moved to `CORS` extension also no way. the issue still the same. Thanks. And sorry my English. I'm not an English speaker.

Comment: I don't quite have enough `Javascript` experience to be able to avoid this issue. But my understanding so far is that this is very possible!

Comment: I have created this example for you
https;//dev.codetron.co.in/test/

1. Right click and see page source to find index.html code.
2. Open https://dev.codetron.co.in/ajax.js to check js code.
3. Open https://dev.codetron.co.in/data.php to check php code.

You can compare and see what difference is there from your code.

Comment: Thanks bro and really appreciate you great time. well, I opened these given links, and everything is working. So far, I don't know what should I do next!